# How to make node module by typescript module

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, node-modules, module-build

How to build  typescript module to javascript module

this is my tsconfigFile

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES5",
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "declaration": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "strict": true,
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true
  }
}
```

I want to Buiding This Code --------------

Typescript Module

```
import getData from './getData';


export default {
 getData 
};
```

node Module

```
const getData = require("./getData")';

module.exports = {
  getData
};
```

Comment: I don't think I understand your question, but to compile TS you need the command tsc.

Answer (score 0):

Since your config seems to have the needed settings to generate node modules, I think you just need to run the `tsc` command, and it will generate the JS code and store it in the `./dist` directory.